# How to copy a number with comma as thousands separator from a cell to an email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, format, numbers

I have an Outlook macro that will reply to the currently selected email within Outlook, asks the user for input and then based on the input it will fill the email with specific information in an Excel workbook (xl).

I'm using `cost = xl.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varInput, ws.Range("A:G"), 5, False)` to look for a value/number based on the user's input and then using the value `cost` in the body of the email. The body is structured with .HTMLBody

I need `cost` to be formatted as number with commas as the thousands separator (3,564). I tried:

```
cost = xl.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varInput, ws.Range("A:G"), 5, False)
cost_format = Format(cost , "#,##0")
```

and then using `cost_format` in the body of the email, but this gives me number with space as the thousands separator (3 564).

Comment: if you add coma type of `dan_k_zaplaceni` variable will be not numeric anymore (string/variant). if you re ok with that you can do simple function that add coma in string `if len(dan_k_zaplaceni) >=4` condition is met

Comment: `dan_k_zaplaceni` is actually suppose to be `cost `. I coppied the wrong code, haha, sorry. This could work, however `cost ` could also be ##,##0 or ###,##0 in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a solution. I pasted a formula `=TEXT (cost, "#,##0")` in the Excel workbook and used that as the result of VLOOKUP in the body of the email.

Now the amounts are showing with commas as the thousands separator in the email.